# Why doesn't the <span> tag behave the same as a <div> tag?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't the circle appear using a span tag, but does with a div tag? 
[FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqb2e9n0/)

```
<span class="circle red"></span>
<div class="circle red"></div>

.circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because span is an inline element and inline elements cannot be given a specific height.

However, you can make an inline element accept a height by making it an inline-block or block level element.

```css
.circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle red"></span>
<div class="circle red"></div>
```